# Does python have some sort of consuming streams?

Tags: python, stream

I'm looking for a "consuming" byte stream in python, behaving like a `Queue`: data would be written at the end while reading would returns and discard data form the beginning of the stream.

I haven't been able to find such things (using keywords like *consuming/rotating/shift streams*), so I feel I'm probably not using the right terminology here.

A dirty implementation of it could be :

```py
from io import BytesIO, SEEK_END

class ConsumingStream(BytesIO):
    """ Stream where write append data to the end and read consumes from the start """

    def write(self, data):
        """ Write bytes to the end of the stream """
        self.seek(0, SEEK_END)
        super().write(data)

    def read(self, size=-1):
        """ Read and consume at most size-bytes from the beginning of the stream """
        self.seek(0)
        data = super().read(size)
        self.shift(len(data))
        return data

    def shift(self, n):
        """ Removes n-bytes from the beginning of the buffer """
        view = self.getbuffer()
        size = len(view)
        view[0:size-n] = view[n:size]
        view.release()
        self.truncate(size-n)

s = ConsumingStream(b'first_second_third')
print(s.read(6))    # first_
print(s.getvalue()) # second_third
```

Ideally, the stream would implement a `getbuffer()` method (as `BytesIO` does here) and be thread-safe (I didn't bothered adding locks in my dirty implementation).

Is there such streams in python ? If not, what could be the most effective implementation of it ?

Comment: A simple pipe (via `os.pipe`) would be the (non-thread-safe) starting point.

Comment: Possibly `collections.deque` (thread-safe) as well.